# Extract objects from this Json string with GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

i need to get an array of Works for this json string:

```
  [
        {
            "worktypes": [
                {
                    "works": [
                        {
                            "price": "22,22",
                            "code": "A00011",
                            "name": "name 2"
                        },
                        {
                            "price": "22,22",
                            "code": "A00011",
                            "name": "name 3"
                        },
                        {
                            "price": "22,22",
                            "code": "A00011",
                            "name": "name 4"
                        },
                        {
                            "price": "11",
                            "name": "aa",
                            "code": "aa"
                        },
                        {
                            "price": "12,22",
                            "name": "Nombre",
                            "code": "A00112"
                        },
                        {
                            "price": "22",
                            "name": "asdads",
                            "code": "asdasd"
                        },
                        {
                            "price": "11",
                            "name": "yy",
                            "code": "yy"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name": "Pompas"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I try this:

```
List<Work> works = gson.fromJson(value.toString(), new TypeToken<List<Work>>() {}.getType());
```

But dont get  anyone..whats wrong?

PD:Work is a class with the price, code and name values.

Comment: Anyone, but works have only one item with null values.

Answer (score 0):

Have another class something WorkTypes.class and have an instance of a ArrayList of Work objects.

```
public class WorkTypes  {

    //worktypes here should match json...character to character!
    private ArrayList<Work> worktypes;

    public ArrayList<Work> getEntities() {
        return worktypes;
    }

    public void setEntities(ArrayList<Work> worktypes) {
        this.worktypes = worktypes;
    }
}
```

Then for GSON, do something like:

```
    WorkTypes objs = null;
    objs = gson.fromJson(jsonDataString, WorkTypes.class);
```

Comment: try this approach and lemme know what do you get...we can also try another approach